# Accessing a class in other namespace but same solution

Tags: c#, reflection

Despite the many examples I still do not get it.

- [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825147/2910930)
- [Resolve Type from Class Name in a Different Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512319/2910930)
- [C# creating instance of class and set properties by name in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11958825/2910930)
- [Activator.CreateInstance: Could not load type from assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28889117/2910930)
- [Could not load type from assembly error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/124841/2910930)
- [Get a new object instance from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/752/2910930)
- [Object reference not set to an instance of an object. C# GetProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20360768/2910930)

I got 1 visualstudio solution with multiple projects inside

1 of those projects is a console application

```
namespace Test
```

--> assembly name is Test

1 of those projects is a class library

```
namespace Mayhem
```

--> assembly name is Mayhem

The class library has multiple classes

```
namespace Mayhem
{
    public class Step1
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can access the class library from the console application. But I would like to access the class library through Reflection. Based on some other solutions I came up with something like this, but it still gives me a TypeLoadException

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] ClassArray = new string[] { "Mayhem.Step1", "Mayhem.Step2" };

        foreach (var item in ClassArray)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType(item, true);

            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("Title");

            prop.SetValue(instance, item, null);

            Console.WriteLine(SetSegment.ToMessageSegment(instance));
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Question: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the full name: "Mayhem.Step1, AssemblyName" where `AssemblyName` would be the actual name of the assembly?

Comment: From the accepted answer on your very first link - "Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName") only works when the type is found in either mscorlib.dll or the currently executing assembly.". Do you believe that either of those conditions are true for your type? And a quick check of the docs confirms that `GetType(string,boolean)` has the same restriction.

Comment: @wiktor which assembly? This string[] ClassArray = new string[] { "Mayhem.Step1,Mayhem", "Mayhem.Step2,Mayhem" }; this is sadly not working.

Comment: @Damien Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName") ==> I dit not fully understand the answer (as I already stated) Type.GetType("Mayhem.?.Step1"); What do I fill in the Answer?

Comment: `Mayhem.Step1, Mayhem` should **definitely** work, unless you miss the reference between assemblies or the class is not public.